# In TypeScript, How to cast boolean to number, like 0 or 1

Tags: javascript, typescript, typecast-operator

As we know, the type cast is called assertion type in TypeScript. And the following code section:

```
// the variable will change to true at onetime
let isPlay: boolean = false;
let actions: string[] = ['stop', 'play'];
let action: string = actions[<number> isPlay];
```

On compiling, it go wrong

```
Error:(56, 35) TS2352: Neither type 'boolean' nor type 'number' is assignable to the other.
```

Then I try to use the `any` type:

```
let action: string = actions[<number> <any> isPlay];
```

Also go wrong. How can I rewrite those code.

Comment: `actions[isPlay ? 1 : 0]`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can't just cast it, the problem is at runtime not only at compile time.

You have a few ways of doing that:

```
let action: string = actions[isPlay ? 1 : 0];
let action: string = actions[+isPlay];
let action: string = actions[Number(isPlay)];
```

Those should be fine with both the compiler and in runtime.

Comment: The second way isn't really self-documenting unless you know that you can do it this way.  Otherwise, the first way is pretty obvious at a glance to any other developers looking at your code.

Answer (score 10):

You can convert anything to boolean and then to a number by using `+!!`:

```
const action: string = actions[+!!isPlay]
```

This can be useful when for example you want at least two out of three conditions to hold, or exactly one to hold:

```
const ok = (+!!something)  + (+!!somethingelse) + (+!!thirdthing) > 1
const ok = (+!!something)  + (+!!somethingelse) + (+!!thirdthing) === 1
```

Comment: Why +!! instead of just +?

Comment: @MarkLopez !! forces the expression to be either true or false, so +!! becomes 0 or 1.  if for example `something` was 4, then +!!4 is 1 while +4 is 4.  so +!! helps you count the number of boolean true expressions.

Comment: `+undefined` is NaN but `+!!undefined` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is not casting, just use boolean type for dictionary keys:

```
@@
-let actions: string[] = ['stop', 'play'];
+let actions: string[] = {false: 'stop', true: 'play'};
```