# Typescript: Use Boolean type in an arithmetic operation

Tags: typescript, types

I want to use a boolean variable in a arithmetic operation in typescript, but the compiler complains: "The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type."

```
class User {
    hasFoo: boolean;
};
let user = new User();
let amount : number = BASE + FOO_FACTOR * user.hasFoo
```

I know that I can cast my boolean to the type `<any>` and it's working:

```
let amount : number = BASE + FOO_FACTOR * <any>user.hasFoo
```

But is it the best solution?

Comment: Why do you want to use a boolean variable in a arithmetic operation? TypeScript is about forcing types. At run-time, your boolean will be casted to a number anyways, so why don't you convert the boolean into a number explicitly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In TypeScript, How to cast boolean to number, like 0 or 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687958/in-typescript-how-to-cast-boolean-to-number-like-0-or-1)

Comment: Note you can also work around this issue by using the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), e.g. `let amount: number = user.hasFoo ? BASE + FOO_FACTOR : BASE;` or `let amount: number = BASE + (user.hasFoo ? FOO_FACTOR : 0);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript wants you to enforce types at compile time. Your code works on runtime due to the internal weak typing of vanilla JavaScript.

Avoid `any` casting, instead convert the `boolean` to an actual `number`.

There are multiple options, e.g.:

```
let number: number = user.hasFoo ? 1 : 0
```

or:

```
let number: number = Number(user.hasFoo)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll use Number() in my function.