# Is there a way I can put more than one string in .includes for React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-native

Right now I have this going where if water or ocean is included in this.state then do this:

```
{this.state.ticket.includes('water') || this.state.ticket.includes('ocean') ?
// do something
:
// do something else
}
```

Is there a simplier way to put all the strings in `.includes` instead of repeating the same `or` code? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple conditions for JavaScript .includes() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896484/multiple-conditions-for-javascript-includes-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below see if it works:

1. make an array of text you want to check.
2. then use `.some` to check each element in the text array is included in the state.

```
var textArray = ['1', '2'];        
var state ='1';

var check = function(element) {return state.includes(element);}         
console.log(textArray.some(check));
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much @Fan!