# Check for discord link and delete

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im trying to code my discord bot to prevent advertising other discords.
I've read a lot on this site, but can't find the solution.
I want the bot to search for discord invites in a message, and if this link is not posted by a member that has the kick permission, then it should delete the invite.

```js
if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/')) { //if it contains an invite link
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
            message.delete() //delete the message
            .then(message.member.send(ms.INVITELINK));
    }}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What error are you receiving?

Comment: The bot is not deleting or sending a message to the user that post's a discord link, regardless they have/have not the kick permission.

Edit: And there is no error's in the console.

Comment: Does your bot have moderator permissions to delete and send messages? Does the code you posted actually reach the if statement before the delete message? `Console.log` a message to see if you're hitting each conditional. Your code looks perfectly fine.

Comment: My bot has moderator rights yes.
https://ibb.co/N990BhB <-- screenshot

Comment: So, i just did the console.log, and im getting 0 hits.

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer.

Comment: Solved.
Had it after a. 
if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes only accepts one condition. You have to use separate include statements if you're using `||` for each of the strings you're trying to catch. If you want to check for multiple conditions try using [`some()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37896529/10746956)

```js
if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/') || message.content.includes('discordapp.com/invite/')) { //if it contains an invite link
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
    message.delete() //delete the message
      .then(message.member.send(ms.INVITELINK));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for all your help :) 
Have a nice day.