# Filter array on multiple attributes on same key

Tags: javascript

I have a json and would like to filter for one key multiple attribites as exact match.

I tried the following:

```js
let data = [{
  "name": "Product 2",
  "link": "/stock/product2",
  "category": "234",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 1",
  "link": "/stock/product1",
  "category": "1231",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 3",
  "link": null,
  "category": "22",
  "description": ""
}]

data = data.filter(cv => cv.category === ["22", "234"]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

I would like to get back the object with the name: `Product 2` and name: `Product 3`.

Any suggestions why I get `[]` back?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I'd do that by multiple `includes()` in filter with `||`, or something like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896484/multiple-conditions-for-javascript-includes-method so you will create `contains` method which requires an array of possible values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using [`Set.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) for your desired attributes, so you can can have `O(1)` lookup time rather than the `O(n)` *(where `n` is the number of desired attributes*) lookup time using [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

As a result, if you use a set the overall the time complexity for the whole filter line will be `O(m)` *(where `m` is the number of objects in `data`)* rather than `O(mn)` if you used [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or had multiple if-else / or conditions to check for each desired attribute:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Product 2",
    link: "/stock/product2",
    category: "234",
    description: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Product 1",
    link: "/stock/product1",
    category: "1231",
    description: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Product 3",
    link: null,
    category: "22",
    description: "",
  },
];

const desiredCategories = new Set(["22", "234"]);

const filteredData = data.filter(cv => desiredCategories.has(cv.category));

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing a single value against an array of values.  One solution would be to check for one value *or* (`||`) the other.

```
data = data.filter(cv => cv.category === "22" || cv.category === "234");
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by the includes method.

```js
let data = [{
  "name": "Product 2",
  "link": "/stock/product2",
  "category": "234",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 1",
  "link": "/stock/product1",
  "category": "1231",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 3",
  "link": null,
  "category": "22",
  "description": ""
}]

data = data.filter(cv => ["22", "234"].includes(cv.category));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Besides, I think this is easy to read/understand.

Answer (score 4):

Check if the item is in the array instead

```
data = data.filter(cv => ["22", "234"].includes(cv.category));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{
  "name": "Product 2",
  "link": "/stock/product2",
  "category": "234",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 1",
  "link": "/stock/product1",
  "category": "1231",
  "description": ""
}, {
  "name": "Product 3",
  "link": null,
  "category": "22",
  "description": ""
}]

const filteredData = data.filter(({ category }) => category === "22" || category === "234");

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData))
```

I wouldn't mutate your original object. Also, you can deconstruct category in the filter function.