# How to filter array of objects with based on value from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, first containing objects and second containing ids. I want to return a new array from the first array that has ids from the first array. What is the best and efficient way to do this?

```
const firstArr = [{id: 1, city: London}, {id: 5, city: 'Berlin'}, {id: 10, city: 'Paris'}, {id: 2, city: 'Rome'}]

const secondArr = ['2', '5']

const wantedArr = [{id: 2, city: 'Rome'}, {id: 5, city: 'Berlin'}]
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include what you've already tried.

Comment: I believe this could possibly be a [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499126/filter-array-on-multiple-attributes-on-same-key/57499181#57499181)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For linear time-complexity convert second array in to set and then use `Set.prototype.has`

```js
const firstArr = [{id: 1, city: 'London'}, {id: 5, city: 'Berlin'}, {id: 10, city: 'Paris'}, {id: 2, city: 'Rome'}]
const secondArr = ['2', '5'];

let set = new Set(secondArr);
const res = firstArr.filter(x => set.has(String(x.id)));

console.log(res)
```

If you want to keep the order of result array according to the `secondArr` then first make a object from `firstArr` and then use `map()` on `secondArr`

```js
const firstArr = [{id: 1, city: 'London'}, {id: 5, city: 'Berlin'}, {id: 10, city: 'Paris'}, {id: 2, city: 'Rome'}]
const secondArr = ['2', '5'];

const obj = firstArr.reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a.id] = a,ac), {});

const res = secondArr.map(x => obj[x]);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
secondArr.map(e => firstArr.filter(a => a.id == +e))
```

I'm using `+e` to cast the string to an int, might not be the best way but certainly the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `.indexOf()` or `.includes()` method

```js
const firstArr = [{ id: 2, city: 'London' }, { id: 2, city: 'Tokyo' }, { id: 5, city: 'Berlin' }, { id: 10, city: 'Paris' }, { id: 6, city: 'Rome' }];

const secondArr = ['2', '5'];

const output = firstArr.filter((r) => {
  return secondArr.includes(`${r.id}`);
});

console.log(output);
```

```js
const firstArr = [{ id: 2, city: 'London' }, { id: 2, city: 'Tokyo' }, { id: 5, city: 'Berlin' }, { id: 10, city: 'Paris' }, { id: 6, city: 'Rome' }];

const secondArr = ['2', '5'];

const output = firstArr.filter((r) => {
  return secondArr.indexOf(`${r.id}`) > -1;
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const wantedArr = firstArr.filter(({ id }) => secondArr.includes(`${id}`));
```