# How to filter by multiple values using .includes?

Tags: javascript

I'm filtering some records according to the their string content using the .includes function.

Here a snap of my code

```js
 var oav = ["baluardo"]

...

  if (((item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"]["_"]).length >= 10 &&
                    (item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"]["_"]).length <= 400) && (item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"]["_"])
                    .includes(oav) 
                    )

... do something ...
```

Using one term the .includes function works properly, adding one more term like this

```js
var oav = ["baluardo", "Fortezza"]
```

doesn't work and I'm having an empty array.

Suggestions?

Regards

Comment: So you want to check if your metadata includes atleast one of those strings in oav or you want to check if your metadata includes all of those strings in oav?

Comment: Make your life easier with an intermediate variable: `const meta = item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"]["_"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple conditions for JavaScript .includes() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896484/multiple-conditions-for-javascript-includes-method)

Comment: @AndrewL64 all of those strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.every()` to check if every element in `oav` is in the metadata.

```js
var oav = ["baluardo", "Fortezza"]

//not actual metadata
var meta = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "baluardo", "Fortezza"];

if (meta.length >= 10 && meta.length <= 400 && oav.every(o => meta.includes(o))) {
  console.log("meta includes baluardo and Fortezza");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two `some()` functions to compare the search terms to the `description` value:

```
const result = searchTerms.some(word => inputArr.some(el => el.desc.includes(word)))
```

```js
function findSearchTerms(inputArr, searchTerms){
    if (inputArr.length >= 0 && inputArr.length <= 10 && searchTerms.some(word => inputArr.some(el => el.desc.includes(word)))){
        console.log("one or more of these elements includes a search term")                   
    }else{
        console.log("none of these elements includes a search term")                   
    }
}


const terms = ["baluardo", "Fortezza"]
let arr = [{desc:"baluardo etc."},{desc:"etc. Fortezza"},{desc:"Other desc"}]

findSearchTerms(arr,terms)

arr = [{desc:"etc."},{desc:"etc."},{desc:"Other desc"}]

findSearchTerms(arr,terms)
```