# check whether two or more words from list(array) are present in the string...javascript

Tags: javascript

I was looking for my answer and found this:
[multiple conditions for JavaScript .includes() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896484/multiple-conditions-for-javascript-includes-method)

but, this solution does either one or all of the words from the list:

```
 //checks for one
 const multiSearchOr = (text, searchWords) => (
searchWords.some((el) => {
  return text.match(new RegExp(el,"i"))
})
)

  //checks for all
 const multiSearchAnd = (text, searchWords) => (
    searchWords.every((el) => {
        return text.match(new RegExp(el,"i"))
   })
 )
```

These work, but i need to be able to match on two or more words in my passed in list. Like the following:

```
  let name = "jaso bour 2";
  let spl = name.split(' ');
  let passed = multiSearchAnd("my name is jason bourne the fourth on the fifth", spl);
  console.log(passed);
```

The variable passed in the above scenario is false but i want it to be true since the strings "jaso" and "bour" are in the searched string.

How do i alter the multiSearchAnd function so it will return true if two or more words are found from the passed in list and not just all of them? Thanks

Comment: My first thought is some form of `filter()` on the `searchWords`, and then check that the filtered array length is >= 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two functions from the solution you found use `Array#some()` and `Array#every()`. These array helpers can only do two things: either *any* element in the array satisfies the condition (so, matching *at least 1*) or *every* element satisfies the condition. You want a specific number, so you can't really easily use these helper functions. However, you *can* do this yourself with a simple loop:

```js
const multiSearchAtLeastN = (text, searchWords, minimumMatches) => {
  let matches = 0;
  for (let word of searchWords) {
    if (text.includes(word) && ++matches >= minimumMatches) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

//demonstration
let name = "jaso bour 2";
let spl = name.split(' ');
let passed = multiSearchAtLeastN("my name is jason bourne the fourth on the fifth", spl, 2);
console.log(passed);
```

This has the benefit of returning the result as soon as one is known, as opposed to other possible solutions involving `.filter()` which would have to iterate the entire array first with no early-exit.

---

If you value concise code, you can also make this work with a clever usage of `Array#some()` with early exit:

```js
const multiSearchAtLeastN = (text, searchWords, minimumMatches) => (
    searchWords.some(word => text.includes(word) && --minimumMatches <= 0)
);

//demonstration
let name = "jaso bour 2";
let spl = name.split(' ');
let passed = multiSearchAtLeastN("my name is jason bourne the fourth on the fifth", spl, 2);
console.log(passed);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This rocks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to build an Array of your matching strings, and then check against the length of this Array

```js
let name = "jaso bour 2";
let spl = name.split(' ');
let passed = multiSearchAnd("my name is jason bourne the fourth on the fifth", spl);

console.log(passed);

function multiSearchAnd(input, matchArr) {
  return matchArr.filter(x => input.includes(x)).length >= 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this