# Returning Filtered Table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

For a practice project, I mapped JSON wine data into a table and created an object defining wines and their attributes(color,taste, body).

**My goal:** If I click the `red` button, a function should check my `wineData` object for what are defined as red wines, and return a filtered table which elements contain in its title strings such as "pinot noir" or "merlot". The JSON data I have is extracted from an external source so it is not predefined. How can I accomplish this? I am having trouble with the filter algorithm.

This is what a piece of the JSON looks like:

```html
        {"key":"38843324","field2":"Charles Krug Pinot Noir","field3":"This elegant, medium-bodied wine features an attractive bouquet of cola, dried cherries and cranberries, and toasted brown sugar.","field4":"Charles Krug","field5":"36.99","field6":"Charles Krug","field7":"750","field8":"ml","field9":""},
```

What my `wineData` object & attributes look like:

```js
var wineData = {

  redWines : [
    {name: "Pinot Noir", body: "Light", taste:"Dry"},
    {name: "Cabernet Sauvignon", body: "Full", taste:"Dry"},
    {name: "Malbec", body: "Full", taste:"Dry"},
    {name:"Zinfadel",body:"Medium",taste:""},
    {name: "Montepulciano", body: "Medium", taste:"Dry"},
    {name: "Merlot", body: "Medium", taste:"Dry"},
  ],

whiteWines : [
  {name: "Chardonnay", body: "Full", taste:"Dry"},
  {name: "Pinot Grigio", body: "Light", taste:"Dry"},
  {name: "Moscato", body: "Light", taste:"Semi-Sweet"},
  {name:"Sauvignon Blanc",body:"Light",taste:"Dry"},
  {name: "Riesling", body: "Light", taste:"Semi-Sweet"},
  {name: "White Zinfadel", body: "", taste:"Sweet"},
]

}
```

my `App` component:

```
      const [wines, setWines] = useState([]);
      let [color, setColor] = useState();
      
      
      var wineData = {

      redWines : [
        {name: "Pinot Noir", body: "Light", taste:"Dry"},
        {name: "Cabernet Sauvignon", body: "Full", taste:"Dry"},
        {name: "Malbec", body: "Full", taste:"Dry"},
        {name:"Zinfadel",body:"Medium",taste:""},
        {name: "Montepulciano", body: "Medium", taste:"Dry"},
        {name: "Merlot", body: "Medium", taste:"Dry"},
      ],

    whiteWines : [
      {name: "Chardonnay", body: "Full", taste:"Dry"},
      {name: "Pinot Grigio", body: "Light", taste:"Dry"},
      {name: "Moscato", body: "Light", taste:"Semi-Sweet"},
      {name:"Sauvignon Blanc",body:"Light",taste:"Dry"},
      {name: "Riesling", body: "Light", taste:"Semi-Sweet"},
      {name: "White Zinfadel", body: "", taste:"Sweet"},
    ]

    }

     useEffect (() =>{
        const fetchWines = async () =>{
          try{
            const response = await api.get('/wines')
            setWines(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(wineData.whiteWines);
            
            


          } catch(err){
            if (err.response){
              console.log(err.response.data);
              console.log(err.response.status);
              console.log(err.response.headers)
            }else{
              console.log(`error: ${err.message}`)
            }

          }
        }
        fetchWines();
      },[])
      
      const handleColorChange = (e) =>{
    setColor(color)
    // console.log(color)
    };

// I think this is where my problem is...
    const filterData = (wines,color) =>{
      if(!color) return wines;
      return wines.filter(wine => wine === color);
    }

    return (
       <>
    
      <Form 
      handleColorChange={handleColorChange}
      color={color}
      setColor={setColor}
    />
      <Table wines={filterData(wines,color)}/>
      </>
      )
```

The `Form` component:

```js
const Form = ({ handleColorChange}) => {

  const handleClick = (e) =>{
    const {color}=e.target.dataset;
    handleColorChange(color);
    console.log(color);
  }
  

  return (
<div>
    {/* <input type="text" value={filteredData} onChange={(e)=>setFilteredData(e.target.value)}></input> */}

    <form onSubmit={(e)=> e.preventDefault()}>

            <Button
            buttonText="Red"
            color="red"
            handleClick={handleClick}
           />
              
            <Button
            buttonText="White"
            color="white"
            handleClick={handleClick}
            
           />

           <Button
           buttonText="reset"
           color=""
           handleClick={handleClick}
           />
          

    </form>
   </div>
  )
}

export default Form
```

`Button` Component:

```js
import React from 'react'

const Button = ({buttonText, color, handleClick}) => {
  return (
    <button
        data-color={color}
        onClick={handleClick}
    >
        {buttonText}
    </button>
    )
}

export default Button
```

`Table` `Row` and `Cell` components

```js
const Table = ({ wines }) => {
  return (
        <table >
            <tbody >
            {wines.map((wine, key) =>(
                    <Row wine={wine} key={key}/>
                ))}

            </tbody>
        </table>
  )
}


const Row = ({ wine }) => {
  return (
   <tr>
       {Object.entries(wine).map(([key, value]) => {
           return (
               <Cell key={key} cellData={JSON.stringify(value)}/>
           )

        } ) }
   </tr>
  )
}

const Cell = ({cellData,wine}) => {
  return (
    <td >
     {cellData}
    </td>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is `field2` the title string mentioned in the My Goal paragraph?

Comment: @BenStephens yes

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible answer (I hope), using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615512/14454939

```
const filterData = (wines, color) => {
  if(!color) return wines;
  return wines.filter(
    (wine) => wine_names[color].some(
      (name) => wine.field2.toLowerCase().includes(name)
    )
  );
};
```

Edit: There also the issue in this function:

```
const handleColorChange = (e) =>{
    setColor(color)
    // console.log(color)
};
```

I think the argument needs to be `color` rather than `e`:

```
const handleColorChange = (color) =>{
    setColor(color)
    // console.log(color)
};
```

```js
const wines = [
  {"key":"1","field2":"Charles Krug Pinot Noir"},
  {"key":"2","field2":"Strange Tidings Merlot"},
  {"key":"3","field2":"Kobold Chef Select Riesling"},
];

const wineData = {
  redWines : [ {name: "Pinot Noir", body: "Light", taste:"Dry"}, {name: "Cabernet Sauvignon", body: "Full", taste:"Dry"}, {name: "Malbec", body: "Full", taste:"Dry"}, {name:"Zinfadel",body:"Medium",taste:""}, {name: "Montepulciano", body: "Medium", taste:"Dry"}, {name: "Merlot", body: "Medium", taste:"Dry"}, ],
  whiteWines : [ {name: "Chardonnay", body: "Full", taste:"Dry"}, {name: "Pinot Grigio", body: "Light", taste:"Dry"}, {name: "Moscato", body: "Light", taste:"Semi-Sweet"}, {name:"Sauvignon Blanc",body:"Light",taste:"Dry"}, {name: "Riesling", body: "Light", taste:"Semi-Sweet"}, {name: "White Zinfadel", body: "", taste:"Sweet"}, ]
};

const wine_names = {
  red: wineData.redWines.map(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase()),
  white: wineData.whiteWines.map(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase()),
};

const filterData = (wines, color) => {
  if(!color) return wines;
  return wines.filter(
    (wine) => wine_names[color].some(
      (name) => wine.field2.toLowerCase().includes(name)
    )
  );
};

const Table = ({ wines }) => {
  return (
    <table >
      <tbody >
        {wines.map((wine, key) =>(
          <Row wine={wine} key={key}/>
        ))}

      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};


const Row = ({ wine }) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      {Object.entries(wine).map(([key, value]) => {
        return (
          <Cell key={key} cellData={JSON.stringify(value)}/>
        )

      } ) }
    </tr>
  )
}

const Cell = ({cellData, wine}) => {
  return (
    <td>
      {cellData}
    </td>
  );
};

const Button = ({ buttonText, color, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      data-color={color}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      {buttonText}
    </button>
  );
};

const Form = ({ handleColorChange }) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const {color}=e.target.dataset;
    handleColorChange(color);
  };
  

  return (
    <div>

      <form onSubmit={(e)=> e.preventDefault()}>

        <Button
          buttonText="Red"
          color="red"
          handleClick={handleClick}
        />

        <Button
          buttonText="White"
          color="white"
          handleClick={handleClick}

        />

        <Button
          buttonText="reset"
          color=""
          handleClick={handleClick}
        />


      </form>
    </div>
  )
};


const App = () => {
  const [wines, setWines] = React.useState([]);
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() =>{
    setWines([
      {"key":"1","field2":"Charles Krug Pinot Noir"},
      {"key":"2","field2":"Strange Tidings Merlot"},
      {"key":"3","field2":"Kobold Chef Select Riesling"},
    ]);
  }, []);

  const handleColorChange = (color) =>{
    setColor(color);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>

      <Form 
        handleColorChange={handleColorChange}
        color={color}
        setColor={setColor}
      />
      <Table wines={filterData(wines,color)}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: this seems to be doing the filtering (showing in the console) but not updating the table with filtered results

Comment: @Shravan Does the edit help?

Comment: yes it worked, thank you! i guess my last question would be, How do i add multiple conditions to that filter algo? So i can filter taste, body, etc.